# IE/EDGE margin-bottom doen't work

Tags: html, css

I have problem with my code. I need have whitespace between the last div (friday_div) and the end of my web page.

HTML code:

```
    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Schedule 613</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="monday">
            <h1>Monday</h1>
            <div id="monday_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tuesday">
            <h1>Tuesday</h1>
            <div id="tuesday_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wednesday">
            <h1>Wednesday</h1>
            <div id="wednesday_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="thursday">
            <h1>Thursday</h1>
            <div id="thursday_div"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="friday">
            <h1>Friday</h1>
            <div id="friday_div"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
 body{
    background-color:lightgray;
    min-width:850px;}
.header{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    min-height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;}
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:90px;
    left:1%;
    width:97.5%;}
.monday,.tuesday,.wednesday,.thursday,.friday{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:250px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;}
.tuesday,.wednesday,.thursday,.friday{
    margin-top:30px;}
.friday{
    margin-bottom:30px;}
```

The problem appears only when i tested project in Internet Explorer browser and EDGE. I used Chrome to test what I did but in Chrome 'margin-bottom' works normal. The problem may also appear in other browsers, but I can not check it out. I hope that somebody help me.

(My level of English is not good enough to explain the problem in more detail, so I wrote here a lot of lines of code to people who know how to solve problems like my problem)

Comment: Chrome is the odd browser out here. You'll have to use a different technique for cross-browser support.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara

Please, tell me more! What does mean odd browser? And how can modify my code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Unfortunately there are several cases in which Chrome's margins behave differently from other browsers. I don't know exactly why, but the solution is generally to avoid using margins in those cases and achieve it by padding or something else.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara
Thank you, Mr. Alexander! I will try remember it and use when be needed. :)

Comment: I think it's because the div is a floating element. Try clearfix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` to `.wrapper`

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:90px;
    left:1%;
    width:97.5%;
    overflow:hidden;  // add this
}
```

Comment: I this case an explanation would be good, telling why that helps (referring the float)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to `.wrapper`
Then change your CSS to:

```
body{
    background-color:lightgray;
    min-width:850px;}
.header{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    min-height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;}
.monday,.tuesday,.wednesday,.thursday,.friday{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:250px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;}
.tuesday,.wednesday,.thursday,.friday{
    margin-top:30px;}
.friday{
    margin-bottom:30px;}
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    top:90px;
    left:1%;
    width:97.5%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```